# Google TV emulation starting up with a non Google TV image and emulator-arm

Tags: google-tv

I have the latest Google TV Addon (rev 2) and the latest emulator. My linux box also supports KVM and when I pass the command kvm-ok, I do get the success messages 
(INFO: Your CPU supports KVM extensions
INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used)

I have created a new AVD via Eclipse using Android AVD and SDK Manager and by setting the Target Name as: Google Tv Addon

However, when I start up the AVD instance (command line or Eclipse), I see a normal Android smartphone instance loading up in the skin of the Google TV (see all the phone apps and nothing happens when I click on the TV specific buttons in the navigation bar). In the verbose logs I do NOT see KVM Auto enabled message and from the excerpts of logs (added below), it looks like the default kernel, system and userdata images are being loaded instead of the images from the /bin/android-sdk-linux_x86/add-ons/addon_google_tv_google_inc_12/images/x86. It also looks like emulator-arm is being executed instead of emulator-x86. Why is this happening? How could I solve this problem? I would greatly appreciate any help in this regard.

```
emulator: Android virtual device file at: <path>/.android/avd/name1.ini
emulator: virtual device content at <path>/.android/avd/name1.avd
emulator: virtual device config file: <path>/.android/avd/name1.avd/config.ini
emulator: using core hw config path: <path>/.android/avd/name1.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: Found AVD target API level: 12
emulator: found skin '720p' in directory: <path>/bin/android-sdk-linux_x86/add-ons/addon_google_tv_google_inc_12/skins
emulator: autoconfig: -skin 720p
emulator: autoconfig: -skindir <path>/bin/android-sdk-linux_x86/add-ons/addon_google_tv_google_inc_12/skins
emulator: keyset loaded from: <path>/.android/default.keyset
emulator: trying to load skin file '<path>/bin/android-sdk-linux_x86/add-ons/addon_google_tv_google_inc_12/skins/720p/layout'
emulator: skin network speed: 'full'
emulator: skin network delay: 'none'
emulator: autoconfig: -kernel <path>/bin/android-sdk-linux_x86/platforms/android-12/images//kernel-qemu
emulator: autoconfig: -ramdisk <path>/bin/android-sdk-linux_x86/platforms/android-12/images//ramdisk.img
emulator: Using initial system image: <path>/bin/android-sdk-linux_x86/platforms/android-12/images//system.img
emulator: autoconfig: -data <path>/.android/avd/name1.avd/userdata-qemu.img
emulator: autoconfig: -initdata <path>/.android/avd/name1.avd/userdata.img
emulator: autoconfig: -cache <path>/.android/avd/name1.avd/cache.img
emulator: Physical RAM size: 1024MB

Content of hardware configuration file:
  hw.cpu.arch = arm
```

....................

Cheers,
S

Answer (score 1):

For a workaround, please try editing the ~/.android/[AVD_name].avd/config.ini file, and change "arm" to "x86" for the hw.cpu.arch and abi.type lines.